# How to configure application to be available subdomain cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, subdomain

I need to share session cookie between main domain and all subdomains. I have two nodejs services based on expressjs framework:

```
// example.local

    ...
    app.use(session({
       cookie: {
          domain: "example.local"
       }
       , key: 'sid'
       , secret: '[my secret]'
       , saveUninitialized: true
       , resave: true
       , store: new RedisStore({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 6379
       })
    })); 

// blog.example.local

    ...
    app.use(session({
       // what should I write here? <---------
    }));
```

So my question is what should I write in session configuration of `blog.example.local` to get access to existing cookie of `example.local`?

**EDIT:** as @yeiniel suggest, I should just use the same config for `blog.example.local` like the following:

```
// blog.example.local

    ...
    app.use(session({
       cookie: {
          domain: "example.local"
       }
       , key: 'sid'
       , secret: '[my secret]'
       , saveUninitialized: true
       , resave: true
       , store: new RedisStore({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 6379
       })
    }));
```

Is it enough or I may optimize it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need two things: Use the same settings on all servers (not just cookie settings but all the session settings included the store) and ensure cookie domain configuration point to the common domain between the sites.

Comment: So I need to just copy and paste settings from `example.local` to `blog.example.local` ?

Answer (score 2):

i think your **cookie** attribute in middleware should be like this,

```
cookie: {
      domain: ".example.local",
      path:'/'
}
```

for **blog.example.local** and

```
cookie: {
      domain: "example.local",
      path:'/'
}
```

for **example.local**

Hope this work you.

Comment: Are you sure? I read that if I need to share cookie for all common domain and subdomains I need to use `domain: "bexample.local"`

Answer (score 1):

I am currently managing a similar setup
All apps have the same settings for session

```
app.use(session({
store: redisStore,
secret: config.secret,
resave: true,
rolling: true,
saveUninitialized: false,
name: config.cookie_name,
cookie: {
  domain: config.cookie_domain_name, \\ .website.tld
  secure: false
}
```

You will not be able to use localhost to keep your session data, specially if apps are on different servers. YOu will need a central storage for session data, which all apps can access.

Comment: Yes I know that I need to separate storage for session but now all my subdomains reside on single machine. So the basic question was about session configs but thanks for pointing! What do you thing about @Lalit Goswami answer?

Comment: All your subdomains do not have to be on the same machine. Only the sessions are being stored centrally. The apps can be on any number of machines.
Also, how you send the Set-Cookie will decide if the subdomains are treated separately or under the main domain.